# c# Connection must be valid and open when fetching multiple tables

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm currently writing a simple program that fetches 4 tables. I can fetch the data all separately but not in a sequence.

DBConnection code:

```
/*
 * Created by SharpDevelop.
 * Date: 13.04.2017
 * Time: 10:29
 */
using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace TWReporting.Database
{
    public class DBConnection
    {
        private DBConnection()
        {
        }

        private string databaseName = "**********";
        private string username = "**********";
        private string password = "**********";

        public string DatabaseName {
            get { return databaseName; }
            set { databaseName = value; }
        }

        public string Password { 
            get { return password; }
            set { password = value; }
        }
        public string Username { 
            get { return username; } 
            set { username = value; }
        }

        private MySqlConnection connection = null;
        public MySqlConnection Connection {
            get { return connection; }
        }

        private static DBConnection _instance = null;
        public static DBConnection Instance()
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new DBConnection();
            return _instance;
        }

        public bool IsConnect()
        {
            bool result = true;
            if (Connection == null) {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(databaseName))
                    result = false;
                string connstring = string.Format("Server=localhost; database={0}; UID={1}; password={2}", databaseName, Username, Password);
                connection = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
                connection.Open();
                result = true;
            }
            return result;
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Example of a method using this:

```
public class DataFetcher
{
    public List<TestSessionDut> duts;
    public List<TestSession> testSessions;
    public List<TestScriptRun> testScriptRuns;
    public List<Engine> engines;

    public DataFetcher()
    {
        duts = new List<TestSessionDut>();
        testSessions = new List<TestSession>();
        testScriptRuns = new List<TestScriptRun>();
        engines = new List<Engine>();
        FetchData();
    }

    public void FetchData()
    {
        FetchDuts();
        FetchEngines();
        FetchTestScriptRuns();
        FetchTestSessions();
    }
    public void FetchDuts()
        {
            var dbCon = DBConnection.Instance();
            try 
            {
                if (dbCon.IsConnect())
                {
                    const string query = "SELECT * FROM table";
                    var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, dbCon.Connection);
                    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while(reader.Read())
                    {
                        var tsd = new TestSessionDut();
                        tsd.ID = reader.GetInt32(0);
                        tsd.Dut = reader.GetString(1);
                        this.duts.Add(tsd);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fetch duts");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                dbCon.Close();
            }
        }
```

I call 4 methods like these but all from a seperate table. I can retrieve data from all the tables separately but when I call the methods all together It will give this message.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you are closing the connection in `FetchDuts` method. Which line of code you are getting error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `IsConnect` method you are initializing the connection if it's null. But next time when you call `IsConnect` the result will remain `false` as connection is not null any more so it won't go inside `if(connection == null)`.

IsConnect method needs to be changed as following.

```
public bool IsConnect()
{
    bool result = false;

    if (connection == null)
    {
        //Checking if all required parameters for connection are having values.
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(databaseName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
        {
            //Creating new connection.
            string connstring = string.Format("Server=.;database={0};UID={1};password={2}", databaseName, Username, Password);
            connection = new SqlConnection(connstring);
        }
    }

    //Check if connection is not null.
    if (connection != null)
    {
        //Check if current status of the connection is open. 
        //If Yes set result = true
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            result = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // If connection not already opened, open it.
            connection.Open();
            result = true;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

And Close method should check for connection object and it's state before closing it.

```
public void Close()
{
    if (connection != null && connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I understand the problem now. Thank you for your answer it was very helpful!